# C# Split string into array based on prior character

Tags: c#, .net

I need to take a string and split it into an array based on the type of charcter not matching they proceeding it.

So if you have "asd fds 1.4#3" this would split into array as follows

```
stringArray[0] = "asd";
stringArray[1] = " ";
stringArray[2] = "fds";
stringArray[3] = " ";
stringArray[4] = "1";
stringArray[5] = ".";
stringArray[6] = "4";
stringArray[7] = "#";
stringArray[8] = "3";
```

Any recomendations on the best way to acheive this? Of course I could create a loop based on .ToCharArray() but was looking for a better way to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "the type of charcter not matching they proceeding it"? Can you give some more explanation and examples?

Comment: Yeah this isn't really clear what you're asking but as a side note, why not use a list?

Comment: Which is the differentiation? Letters, digits and other chars? Or which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of Regular Expressions and link you can do the following.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

var str="asd fds 1.4#3";
var regex=new Regex("([A-Za-z]+)|([0-9]+)|([.#]+)|(.+?)");

var result=regex.Matches(str).OfType<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
```

Add additional capture groups to capture other differences.  The last capture `(.+?)` is a non greedy everything else.  So every item in this capture will be considered different (including the same item twice)

Update - new revision of regex

```
var regex=new Regex(@"(?:[A-Za-z]+)|(?:[0-9]+)|(?:[#.]+)|(?:(?:(.)\1*)+?)");
```

This now uses non capturing groups so that `\1` can be used in the final capture.  This means that the same character will be grouped if its in then catch all group.

e.g. before the string "asd  fsd" would create 4 strings (each space would be considered different) now the result is 3 strings as 2 adjacent spaces are combined

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
var mc = Regex.Matches("asd fds 1.4#3", @"([a-zA-Z]+)|.");
var res = new string[mc.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
{
    res[i] = mc[i].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This program produces exactly output you want, but I am not sure wether it's generic enaugh for your goal.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var splited = Split("asd fds 1.4#3").ToArray();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(string text)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var ch in text)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(ch))
            {
                result.Append(ch);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return result.ToString();
                result.Clear();
                yield return ch.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }

}
```